# If never executes, even though it's true

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having an issue with this global variable. It never executes the If sentence, even though it is true.

HTML:

```
<p onclick="change(this)">Click</p>
<p onclick="change2(this)">Click</p>
```

JavaScript:

```
var status = false;
localStorage.setItem("status", status);

function change(obj) {
    var status = localStorage.getItem("status");
    var status = true;
    localStorage.setItem("status", status);
}

function change2(obj) {
    var status = localStorage.getItem("status");
    alert(status)
    if (status == true) {
        alert("The code works");
    } else {
        alert("The code doesn't work");
```

The alert(status) returns true, but right after that, I get "The code doesn't work". I'm really puzzled by this issue.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: because `"true" == true` is false - localStorage deals with strings - try `if(status == "true")` instead

Comment: I wonder if the data store contains variable type.  Could the true you alert be a string?  If so, json might be a good fix as it would distinguish Boolean, string, and decimal types as well as arrays and key value hashes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) :

```
localStorage.setItem("status", status);
```

adds as key and value a [DOMString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString) that is a UTF-16 String.

> keyName
>
> A DOMString containing the name of the key you want to create/update.
>
> keyValue
>
> A DOMString containing the value you want to give the key you are
>   creating/updating.

As JavaScript already uses such strings, DOMString is mapped directly
to a **String**.

So you compare a String with a `boolean` here :

```
if (status == true) {
```

It is equivalent to :

```
if ("true" == true) {
```

that is evaluated to `false` as it compare `NaN` to `1` after numeric conversion (`true` being convertible in `number`).

So as workaround you could compare strings:

```
if (status === "true") {
```

Comment: I hasten to add that storing json would be an elegant solution.

Comment: It may. But why not simply compare `statut` to "true" ?

Comment: This has solved my problem, never would I have imagined that it saved it as a String! Thanks!

Comment: Great. I was like you before reading the doc about it . Don't hesitate to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

By using `var status` in your functions, you're creating a locally-scoped variable called `status` in your function vs. modifying the globally scoped variable you created at the top of your file.

Just remove the `var` from your assignments.

Comment: I've just removed `var` from all declarations, and it is still not working.

Comment: But wouldn't it be valid to set and retrieve  into a local scoped variable?  In other words, it seems that your explanation doesn't really explain why it wouldn't work as coded.

Comment: This is just outright _wrong_. The problem is not global vs local, it is (as commented and answered) string vs. boolean.